# Character getting distorted while Parenting to bones

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm trying to teach myself how to rig for the first time and after finally getting somewhere with it, but my mesh gets distorted when I try to parent it to the bones with automatic weights. I don't know where else to go from here.
[image]

This is the mesh before Parenting.[image]

Notice how the body and the legs are skewed and distorted.
I've removed doubles, and I've removed modifiers and still it gets distorted.

Comment: most of the times, perenting needs adjustments with Weight Painting or Vertex Groups, so it's not a surprise if it doesn't work fine, please share your file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the origin of the armature being different from the one of the model. Try setting both origins to the same point and then try it again.